# Label que se modifica en función a una operación

Tags: python, tkinter

Estoy intentando hacer un programa en Python con Tkinter que calcule el IMC, y en base al resultado tiene que aclarar si es Peso normal, sobrepeso, etc. El problema es que no logro hacer que el Label de el tipo de peso se modifique. No importa el resultado que de la operación, siempre se queda estancado en "Peso inferior al normal", como muestra en la imagen. Les dejo el código que me parece relevante para la ayuda, y una imagen. Gracias!.

```
        self.__peso= StringVar()
        self.__estatura= StringVar()
        self.__mci= DoubleVar()
        self.__tipo_mci= StringVar()

        tk.Button(mainframe, text="Calcular", bg='#5cba5c',fg= '#ffffff', height = 1, width = 20, command=self.calcular).grid(column=2, row=3, sticky=E)  
        tk.Label(mainframe, text=f"Tu Indice de Masa Corporal (IMC) es: ",fg='#6d8c68',bg='#e1f0d9').grid(column=2, row=5, columnspan= 3, sticky= W)
        tk.Label(mainframe, textvariable= self.__mci, fg='#6d8c68',bg='#e1f0d9', font=negrita).grid(column=3, row=5, sticky=E)
        tk.Label(mainframe, text="kg/m2",fg='#6d8c68',bg='#e1f0d9').grid(column=5, row=5, sticky= N)
        
        
        if self.__mci.get() < 18.5:
            self.__tipo_mci.set("Peso inferior al normal")
            
        elif self.__mci.get() >= 18.5 and self.__mci.get() < 25:
            self.__tipo_mci.set("Peso normal")
            
        elif self.__mci.get() >= 25 and self.__mci.get() < 30:
            self.__tipo_mci.set("Sobrepeso")
            
        elif self.__mci.get() >= 30:
            self.__tipo_mci.set("Obesidad")
            
        labelmci= tk.Label(mainframe, text= self.__tipo_mci, font=tipo_imc,fg='#6d8c68',bg='#e1f0d9')
        labelmci.grid(column=1, row=6, columnspan= 4, sticky= N)  
        
        for child in mainframe.winfo_children():
            child.grid_configure(padx=5, pady=5)     
            
        self.estaturaEntry.focus()
        self.__ventana.mainloop()
        
    def calcular(self):
         try:
             m2= float(self.estaturaEntry.get())
             peso= float(self.pesoEntry.get())
             self.__mci.set('{0:.2f}'.format(peso / ((m2/100)*(m2/100))))          
         
         except ValueError:
             messagebox.showerror(title='Error', message='Debe ingresar un valor numérico')
             self.__estatura.set('')
             self.__peso.set('')
             self.estaturaEntry.focus()
      
def testAPP():
    mi_app = Aplicacion()
 
testAPP()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asumo que la primera parte del código es parte del inicializador de la clase `Aplicacion` o de un método llamado directamente por el mismo. Si es así, no se modifica porque jamás lo modificas una vez que la aplicación se muestra.

El inicializador se ejecuta una sola vez en ésta línea:

```
mi_app = Aplicacion()
```

al momento de instanciar la clase después de que `__new__` retorne el objeto, por tanto tu bloque condicional se ejecuta en ese momento, antes del mainloop, antes de que la app se muestre siquiera. Lo que el usuario haga después no influye para nada, el condicional no se volverá a ejecutar.

El código encargado de actualizar los widgets debe ejecutarse cuando el usuario pulse el botón en éste caso, es decir, debe ir en la callback asociada al botón, el método de instancia `calcular`.

Por otro lado, en el label encargo de mostrar el tipo no asocias la variable oportuna (self.__tipo_mci), sino solo su texto en ese momento de forma estática. Debe ser `textvariable=self.__tipo_mci` y no `text=self.__tipo_mci`

Por cierto, es muy mala práctica incluir la llamada al mainloop en el inicializador, `__init__` debe retornar nada más instanciar la clase, no quedarse bloqueado por el mainloop.

Debería ser algo así:

```
        self.__peso = StringVar()
        self.__estatura = StringVar()
        self.__mci = DoubleVar()
        self.__tipo_mci = StringVar()

        tk.Button(
            mainframe, text="Calcular", bg='#5cba5c',fg='#ffffff', height=1,
            width=20, command=self.calcular
            ).grid(column=2, row=3, sticky=E) 

        tk.Label(
            mainframe, text=f"Tu Indice de Masa Corporal (IMC) es: ",
            fg='#6d8c68', bg='#e1f0d9'
            ).grid(column=2, row=5, columnspan= 3, sticky=W)

        tk.Label(
            mainframe, textvariable=self.__mci, fg='#6d8c68', 
            bg='#e1f0d9', font=negrita
            ).grid(column=3, row=5, sticky=E)

        tk.Label(
            mainframe, text="kg/m2",fg='#6d8c68',bg='#e1f0d9'
            ).grid(column=5, row=5, sticky=N)
            
        tk.Label(
            mainframe, textvariable=self.__tipo_mci, font=tipo_imc,
            fg='#6d8c68', bg='#e1f0d9'
            ).grid(column=1, row=6, columnspan=4, sticky=N)  
        
        for child in mainframe.winfo_children():
            child.grid_configure(padx=5, pady=5)     
            
        self.estaturaEntry.focus()

    def mainloop(self):
        self.__ventana.mainloop()
        
    def calcular(self):
         try:
             m2 = float(self.estaturaEntry.get())
             peso = float(self.pesoEntry.get())         
         except ValueError:
             messagebox.showerror(
                 title='Error', message='Debe ingresar un valor numérico'
                 )
             self.__estatura.set('')
             self.__peso.set('')
             self.estaturaEntry.focus()
         else:
             mci = peso / ((m2 / 100) * (m2 / 100))
             self.__mci.set('{0:.2f}'.format(mci)          
             if mci < 18.5:
                 self.__tipo_mci.set("Peso inferior al normal")
            
             elif  18.5 <= mci < 25:
                 self.__tipo_mci.set("Peso normal")
            
             elif 25 <= mci < 30:
                self.__tipo_mci.set("Sobrepeso")
             
             else:
                 self.__tipo_mci.set("Obesidad")
      
def test_app():
    mi_app = Aplicacion()
    mi_app.mainloop()
 

if __name__ == "__main__":
    test_app()
```